# How to hide and toggle content

Tags: jquery, visual-web-developer

How can I hide a content without disturbing the rest of my content in jQuery? I need to toggle also?

`.css{visibility:hidden}`

doesn't help me toggle.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see what and how to ask. Then search jQuery documentation for toggle. Then close the question since you found the answer. If you need the object to take up place, change the opacity

Answer (score 0):

Use display: 'block' to show and display: 'none' to hide using jQuery's css function.

You can toggle:

```
   var toggle=0;

   $('#togglebutton').click(function(){
    if (toggle == 0) {
        toggle = 1;
        $('#hideshow').css('display', 'block');
    } else {
        toggle = 0;
        $('#hideshow').css('display', 'none');
    }});
```

Sorry I'm answering on my cellphone!

Display: 'block' and none display:'none' are preferable in situations where you want the content to load hidden (say on document ready) without transition effect graphical anomalies. Hide can cause quirky things to happen.

Answer (score 0):

You can toggle any element like p or also particular class or id.

```
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $("button").click(function(){
    $("your_element_neme").toggle();
  });
 });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `.css{visibility:hidden}`, then `.hide()` and `.show()` won't work for you.

**USE:**

```
$('#content').css('visibility', 'visible');
```

and

```
$('#content').css('visibility', 'hidden');
```

and toggle accordingly (as @**adam** said in his answer)